# how can i use a control in template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Style x:Key="abc" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <button x:name="btn">my button!!</button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
...
<Window ... Style="{StaticResource styleMainWindow}">
```

How can i use the button `btn`?

come up to your expectations,

```
MessageBox.Show(this.btn1.name);
```

was occured an error at compile time. and also btn1 didn't show up in intelisense.

Comment: Are you trying to create a lookless Control or a UserControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) method on the ControlTemplate class.

Assuming **this** is your Control's context:

```
var button = (Button)this.Template.FindName("btn", this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess mjk6026, you have misunderstood WPF templates from actual member elements of a window.

It is true that when we name a UI element (x:Name) that is not part of any template, we can access that element by name in the code behind.

For templates you would have to use Template type's FindName() method.

So assuming that `this' means the window to which you have applied your style,  the way you can access the button is (Button)this.Template.FindName("btn", this)

Let me know if this answers your question...

Comment: thanks. and i think of a new question.

[1. a button 'btn' that added from xaml code of window directly.]
[2. a button 'btn' that added from template. (window applied this template)]

no.1 can access like this : debug.writeline(this.btn.name); but no.2 can't.

what make this different?

Comment: @mjk6026, yes an element added to the window directly w/o template is accessible using this.btn. Templates are placeholder factory UIs which are loaded at run time as a part of the visual tree. Although you can set templates at design time, they take effect only at run time. SO their symbols \ element parts are resolved at run time and thus they cannot be accessed as part of "this" irrespective of whether they are named or not. Their name is locally scoped to the template and not to the level of window. I hope that answers your question.